# How to run system commands in Octave for OPM flow reservoir simulator?

Tags: matlab, octave

I do research in oil simulation,  I normally use a simulator called Eclipse from a company called Schlumberger and I was able to use it from my scripts from Matlab using the following command.

```
 % file name 'ICFM.DATA'; 
 system(['eclrun',' eclipse ', C:Path\ICFM.DATA]); % Command to run ECLIPSE
```

Now I had installed a new Free simulator (OPM.org) in linux and I am using Octave for programming.  but I am unable to find out how to run simulator from Octave.

The simulator can be run simply by writing

```
flow ICFM.DATA
```

and the results using a command

```
ecl_summary ICFM.DATA
```

I want to be able to run and get the results from with in Octave but I have not being able as in Matlab.

Any suggestions? someone?

Comment: Octave is not a 1-to-1 replacement for Matlab. Why do you think this should work? Can you show more code around this to give context to the problem?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "GNU OCtave vs. MATLAB" but with your changed underlying simulator. Please add how you would call it in a terminal (with it's output) and how you do this in GNU Octave with `system`

Comment: I think I did the mistake of not mentioning that I am using Ubuntu. And I swap back to Maltab. So I will post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both the `flow` and `ecl_summary` commands are on your system path (i.e. the "linux" path, not in octave), then it should simply be a matter of:

```
system('flow /my/path/to/ICFM.DATA');
system('ecl_summary /my/path/to/ICFM.DATA');
```

(where you should change `/my/path/to` with whatever path your data file is in).

Comment: I can just guess that `ecl_summary` outputs some result on stdout and he wants to use this in GNU Octave so he might want `[status, output] = system (...)`

Comment: I asked a developer on the OPM flow simulator and he told me that: system("flow_ebos DATAFILE.DATA") should work.   
I try that but it still does not run.
I try with a OPM Flow syntaxes that include the flow path but it does not work either.  I will ask in a new post.

Comment: I found that the error was not on the syntaxis but that Matlab was routing the system command incorreclty.  I used the content bellow to solve the issue.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/719028/version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I found that I am able to run the simulation using the syntaxes

```
unix('flow ICFM.DATA')
```

This is in Matlab R2017b for Ubuntu 16.04

Initially I got an error as the output was reporting:

```
....'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

All the problem was due to a Matlab issue that was solved using the answer on
https://askubuntu.com/questions/719028/version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-found
which was to type:

```
LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6" matlab
```

on the terminal.